# use data from ng-repeat in @ajax.actionlink

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs, model-view-controller

I'm trying to load som dynamic data into a @ajax.actionlink

```
<tr ng-repeat="child in row.child" ng-if="row.visible" class="expand-wrapper">                         
    <td>
        @Ajax.ActionLink("{{child.contractname}}", "home", "index", new { value = "{{child.contractId}}" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "window.location.reload()" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

the link text data is rendered fine, but the `value = "{{child.contractId}}"` is not rendered at all. it gives me this `url =  someurl/home?value=%7B%7Bchild.contractId%7D%7D`

Comment: Add some real code, and format it well before anyone is going to try and solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

`<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")/{{child.contractId}}" target="_self">Index</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use MVC Html Helper in this way as your code is generate on server side. And curly bracket are converted into %7B
That should helps

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-success="window.location.reload()" href="/index/home?value={{child.contractname}}">{{child.contractname}}</a>
```